NullPointerException Spark Scala when calling dataset in main from test class
I am trying to call a function that is defined in my Main Scala application from within a Test class. The function returns a Dataset of a class that is also defined in my Main app.
I want the data to be returned in my Test class, so I can compare it with an expected dataset (which I also create in the Test class).
When I execute my code, I get the following error:
java.lang.NullPointerException was thrown.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at assignment.Main$.nr_drives_by_month(Main.scala:96)

Here is a simplified, redacted version of:
Main Class
package assignment
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.to_date
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import java.sql.Date


object Main extends App {

  Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

  val drive_data_location = "data/input/driveData.csv"
  val person_data_location = "data/input/person.csv"

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder
    .master("local[1]")
    .appName("driver_analytics")
    .getOrCreate()

  spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 1)

  import spark.implicits._

  // define schema for a person
  case class Person(personId: Int,
                             firstName: String,
                             lastName: String)

  // define schema for a drive
  case class Drive(personId: Int,
                          driveId: Int,
                          date: String)

  case class driveAggMonthly(Month: Int,
                              numberOfDrives: BigInt)


  val drives = spark.read
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("charset", "UTF8")
    .option("delimiter", ",")
    .option("dateformat", "yyyy-MM-dd")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .csv(drive_data_location)
    .as[Drive]
    .cache()

  val persons = spark.read
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("charset", "UTF8")
    .option("delimiter", ",")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .csv(person_data_location)
    .as[Person]
    .cache()


  def nr_drives_by_month(input_ds: Dataset[Drive]): Dataset[driveAggMonthly] = {
    input_ds
      .groupBy(month(to_date(col("date"))).as("Month"))
      .agg(count(col("driveId")).as("numberOfDrives"))
      .as[driveAggMonthly]
  }

}

Test Class
package assignment

import assignment.Main._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession}
import org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite

class MainTest extends AnyFunSuite {

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder
    .master("local[1]")
    .appName("driver_analytics")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  // Unit Tests:
  test("monthlyAgg") {

    val source_ds = Seq(
      Drive(1, 5, "2023-01-01"),
      Drive(2, 6, "2023-02-01"),
      Drive(3, 7, "2023-02-05"),
      Drive(4, 8, "2024-03-01")
    ).toDS()

    val result_ds_t1: Dataset[driveAggMonthly] = nr_drives_by_month(source_ds: Dataset[Drive])

    val expected_ds_t1 = Seq(
      driveAggMonthly(1, 1),
      driveAggMonthly(2, 2),
      driveAggMonthly(3, 1)
    ).toDS()
    
    assert(result_ds_t1 === expected_ds_t1)
  }
}

Getting rid of the .as[driveAggMonthly] and returning a Dataframe or a Unit works. Also, adding the function (number_drives_by_month) to the Tests class works. However, I don't want either of those things!

Based on what is detailed in spark - self contained applications, "... Note that applications should define a main() method instead of extending scala.App. Subclasses of scala.App may not work correctly...", you could be getting the NPE because of that. I would also suggest to search about the difference between extends trait App and have a main method

In addition to Gastón's general comment you should have your classes for Dataset usage defined at the top level.  Spark's in-built encoder usage relies on reflection (using top level only) and will not complain if there is an issue until runtime, but this is a typical pitfall.
